# Similar Entry in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I posted to:

```
http://localhost:9200/cities/city/1

{
"zip": "84359",
"city": "Simbach"
}
```

Now i wanted to find Simpach which is exactly 2 letters wrong:

```
http://localhost:9200/cities/_search

{
    "query": {
       "fuzzy": {
           "city" : {
               "value" : "Simpdach",
               "fuzziness" : 30
           }

       }
    }
```

but i dont get any result.
I already saw this entry on stackoverflow and i cant find out, what i am doing wrong:

[Fuzzy string matching using Levenshtein algorithm in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748164/fuzzy-string-matching-using-levenshtein-algorithm-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

Check your mapping and make sure `city` field is analyzed.
Something like:

```
PUT /fuzzy_products/product/_mapping
{
  "product": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "simple
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Check "simple fuzzy match" section](https://www.found.no/foundation/fuzzy-search/). I hope it will be helpful.